# How do I create multiple toggling buttons?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create an accordion. It works great when there is only one item. Whenever I try to add same div below my code, it crashes. What do I have to do so this code works for multiple same divs?

```js
var panel = document.querySelector(".panel");
var button = document.querySelector(".accordion");

button.addEventListener("click", function() {
  if (panel.style.display === "none") {
    panel.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    panel.style.display = "none";
  }
});
```

```css
.panel {
  display: none
}
```

```html
<button class="accordion" id="accordion">Section 1</button>
<div class="panel" id="panel">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempo
</div>
```

I want it like this

```
<button class="accordion" id="accordion" >Section 1</button>
<div class="panel" id="panel">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempo
</div>

<button class="accordion" id="accordion" >Section 2</button>
<div class="panel" id="panel">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempo
</div>
```

Comment: You want to have multiple `div` elements which will be shown/hidden using `section 1` button?

Comment: I want to add another button and div class below. So I have couple of buttons in a column with different questions. I want it to work it like accordion for questions.

Comment: I've edited my question with example.

Comment: See this [demo](https://jsbin.com/wojemaluqi/1/edit?html,css,js,output)

Answer (score 0):

Rather than rely on `id`'s, reference the panels via their position, relative to the button element that is clicked. And, rather than set up event handlers for each button, use [event delegation](https://javascript.info/event-delegation) and set one handler up on a container of the whole structure.

Also, don't use inline styles. The [`classList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) API is very simple and helpful here.

Lastly, having a `p` inside of a `div` is redundant.

```js
// Get all the panels into a collection
let panels = document.querySelectorAll(".panel");

// Set up one event handler on a container of all the buttons and panels
document.querySelector(".accordion").addEventListener("click", function(event) {

  // First, hide all the panels
  panels.forEach(function(panel){
    panel.classList.add("hidden");
  });

  // If a button was clicked
  if(event.target.classList.contains("btn")){  
    // Now, show just the selected panel
    event.target.nextElementSibling.classList.toggle("hidden");
  }
});
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none
}

.btn { display:block; }
```

```html
<section class="accordion">
  <button class="btn">Section 1</button>
  <p class="panel hidden">
    1 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempo
  </p>

  <button class="btn">Section 2</button>
  <p class="panel hidden">
    2 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempo
  </p>

  <button class="btn">Section 3</button>
  <p class="panel hidden">
    3 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempo
  </p>

  <button class="btn">Section 4</button>
  <p class="panel hidden">
    4 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempo
  </p>
</section>
```